# String Padding Not Calculating as Expected

Tags: php

I'm displaying numbers being vertically added and trying to draw a line below the numbers being added but above the total.

I'm using a fixed-width font, making the line the width of the widest part of the equation, and trying to keep everything lined up.

This works well, but I'm not a fan of the breaks between the dashes:

```
str_pad(str_repeat('-', $width), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

I'd like to use the character below, but I can't get it to line up:

```
str_pad(str_repeat('─', $width), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

If `$width` is 3, I'd expect 7 spaces followed by 3 wide dashes. That's what I get with the first line but the second line gives me 4 spaces and 3 wide dashes.

Comment: Please give use any example. I did not understand your question

Comment: Well, in your second example you closes two functions `str_pad(str_repeat('&#x2500;'), $width`)`, 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);` at a look before 10 and ,

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo when I was writing this question. Basically my question is how can I get str_pad to work with the second dash? It's not counting as expected and giving me far less padding than it should.

Comment: what do you expect to get at the second line?

Comment: Just a unrelated question, can you use css?